# How to copy string from a column by a condition

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I have this situation:

```
Column
00000000 H0200 5555
H2000 OOOOO4344p H2300
B1500 00000 R2222
B1000
```

This is just one a column, and I need to take the first values that start with H or B for each row, this way:

```
Column
H0200
H2000
B1500
B1000
```

I tried several commands gsub, strsplit, substr etc. But I couldn't to do the condition for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is `str_extract` from `stringr` by matching the 'H' or (`|`) 'B' character from the word boundary (`\\b`) followed by one more more digits (`\\d+`) and the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
library(stringr)
df1$Column <- str_extract(df1$Column, "\\b(H|B)\\d+\\b")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sapply(strsplit(d$Column, " "), function(s)
    s[substring(s, 1, 1) %in% c("H", "B")][1])
#[1] "H0200" "H2000" "B1500" "B1000"
```

OR

```
sub(".*?([H|B]\\w+).*", "\\1", d$Column)
#[1] "H0200" "H2000" "B1500" "B1000"
```

**DATA**

```
d = structure(list(Column = c("00000000 H0200 5555",
                              "H2000 OOOOO4344p H2300", 
                              "B1500 00000 R2222",
                              "B1000")),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```